# yarn.lock file is not updating after I update the version of a dependency in package.json and run yarn install or just yarn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, yarnpkg, lockfile

In the repository of a project, I already have `package.json` and `yarn.lock` files. I'm updating the version of a particular package from version `2.0.14` to version `2.0.16`.

When I do `yarn install` or just `yarn`, I can see the changes related to the updated package but the `yarn.lock` file is not updating.

Is there is any command to generate the updated `yarn.lock` file?

Comment: Could you please describe what commands are you running. If there was a package update then your .lock file should be updated, it is default behaviour.

Comment: I was using yarn install and also yarn as well but the  lock file is not updating

Comment: Something else it is happening there. Please read carefully the documentation: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/install/ your are probably missing something in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `yarn install --force` as this will re-download all packages (in their locked versions unless too old) and refresh the lock file if necessary. `yarn install` should already do this, but in case it doesn't, you can force it to.